# How is the data type (returned from malloc) casted?

Tags: c++, malloc

I mistakenly wrote in C++:

```
Tree *tree = (Tree *)malloc(sizeof (TreeNode));
```

`Tree` and `TreeNode` are two different custom data structures. But it was working without any issues, why? what could be the future problems?

Comment: It depends, c++ It's mandatory but like `static_cast<int *>`, and in c thre is a very famous question. In c++ use `new` instead, because `malloc()` does not call constructors.

Comment: In C++ you should really not use `malloc` and friends at all. It can lead to *undefined behavior* if you're not careful. And remember, C and C++ are two ***very different*** languages, especially when it comes to semantics and behavior.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi thanks. I didn't get your point "It depends, c++ It's mandatory but like static_cast<int *>" can you explain further.

Comment: @MosabShaheen In c++ not casting `void *` explicitly doesn't work and also, you should use c++ style casts instead of `(int *)` which is actually equivalent to `reinterpret_cast<int *>` and is used in a different context, there is a runtime difference between different casts.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi - No, not really. For all but the most trivial types. You'd need to do something like `std::vector` does. So might as well just use vector.

Comment: As for your questions @Mosab: (Q1) #2 is better, it's idiomatic. (Q2) #1 is better, since it's the only one that will compile. But that's still not how C++ is written idiomatically.  (Q3) It worked because you left you code with undefined behavior. Could appear to work. That's why we don't use malloc in C++. That's way anything that requires you to cast is just a way to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @StoryTeller thank you

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi could you remove the duplicate mark. I reduced the question to a smaller one.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can always do a `reinterpret_cast<>` from `void *` to any pointer type, and the compiler would not check that, also note that the real issue is that you are using the wrong `size` parameter for `malloc()` which might or not be bad, depending on whether it's smaller or bigger. But there's not problem related to the initialization of `tree` as the wrong type in this situation, although in c++ you are in a big risk of causing undefined behavior for the reason that will be explained breifly below.

In general, experienced c programmers would do

```
Tree *tree = malloc(sizeof *tree);
```

but this is *invalid c++*, in c++ you would need

```
Tree *tree = static_cast<Tree *>(malloc(sizeof *tree));
```

which would ALWAYS allocate the correct size. But note that this requires the type to appear on both sides of the expression anyway which is not necessay in c.

Now the real c++ way to do this is,

```
Tree *tree = new Tree;
```

This would,

1. Allocate the correct amount of memory.
2. Be typesafe (*it would be an error if you do `Tree *tree = new TreeNode;`*).
3. Call any constructors for `Tree`.

as with `malloc()` you need to manually `free()` this memory but with `delete` instead, like this

```
delete tree;
```

In short, `malloc()` is almost NEVER needed in c++ because you can do most things without it. It still exits because it is useful sometimes but specially for library writers, application writers shall never use it.

Comment: "_Basically you can always do a reinterpret_cast<> from void * to any pointer type_" It's a `static_cast`